# C#. Вызов базового конструктора после конструктора наследника

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("мир!");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Привет ");
    }
}
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы метод конструктора класса `A` после конструктора класса `B`.

В результате, должно вывестись на консоль:

> Привет мир!

Comment: У Вас в коде вообще нет наследования. А если будет, то конструктор базового класса **всегда вызывается до** конструктора производного.

Comment: @alexolut спасибо за замечание, поправил.
То есть так как я хочу сделать не получиться?
Просто у меня развёрнута тут целая иерархия и надо, чтобы самый базовый класс выполнял одну задачу в конструкторе, но только после того, как выполнятся другие задачи.
Теперь надо будет везде добавлять по 1 строчке и не ошибиться.

Comment: Возможно Вам нужно просто изменить код самих конструкторов до достижения нужного эффекта.

Comment: @alexolut возможно это единственное решение, хоть и не самое оптимальное в моём случае.

Comment: Это всяко лучше, чем добиваться чтоб конструктор базового класса выполнялся после производного :)

Comment: @alexolut не лучше, но лучше чем ничего :D

Comment: Сделайте виртуальный метод, который будет вызываться в базовом конструкторе и переопределяйте его в наследниках явно вызывая этот же метод родителей когда вам надо.

Comment: ...но помните, что вызов виртуальных методов в конструкторе обычно плохая идея.

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор базового класса выполняется **перед** конструктором производного класса. Конструкторы экземпляров выполняются в порядке A -> B.

*Пример:*

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello ");
    }
}

public class B: A
{
    public B() : base()
    {
        Console.Write("world!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
    }
}
```

> Hello world!

Comment: Это и так понятно, но как сделать наоборот?

Comment: @PlasticBlock, Нет, так нельзя.